# 3D Scattered Interpolation in C#

Tags: c#, math, 3d, interpolation

I have been looking for a C# (C or C++ equivalents are fine too) equivalent of Mathlabs TriScatteredInterp or scatteredInterpolant methods.

What I have is a matrix of x, y, z points that is my base data. I want then to use those to create an interpolant where I can send new x,y values and get a z-value back. For example, lets assume I have the following data:

0                    2,27869819312637   853,922374575371

1,98605233685976    2,06708520671126    837,753747324253

3,90229069472608    1,88752766631698    823,029331096166

5,75551273267257    1,73306236324839    809,260707800665

7,54873798463369    1,59817317688994    796,049456606332

9,28197384246315    1,47842437187912    783,061777856689

10,9534957278425    1,37052388894339    770,064642137392

12,5656687239417    1,27364051243946    757,204621862504

14,1251442365748    1,18794371439132    744,781009547588

15,642287566849     1,11385507647315    733,134144366184

I want to send x = 1.7, y = 2.2 and get a z for that position.

I am currently using Math.Net, but I don't see how it can help me with points in 3-dimensions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this data set doesn't provide a good grid, because points form chain-like structure rather than net.

If you'll have 3d points, whose projections to XY plane are scattered enough, you can build triangulation (of some kind, e.g. Delaunay one). Then for given x,y coordinates find proper triangle and find interpolated Z-value.

[image]

Comment: So triangulation is the way to go then and as I suspected Delaunay is an alternative. Is there some implementation available or do I need to do this from scratch (Read the math, understand the method and code it)?